# Is it feasible to rely on setlocale, and rely on locales being installed?

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, setlocale, zend-locale

I was trying to generate a localized date string with `strftime`, the placeholder I use is `%x`. The language/locale is `setlocale(LC_ALL, array('jp','japanese'))`, however neither locale was available so it generated a string with improper characters. I then installed the `ja_JP.utf8` locale and specified that as the first element in the array and the date formatting issue I had was resolved.

My question is, should I always rely on locales being installed? I'm aware of how to install them on boxes I have root access to, but what if I don't have access?

I believe `Zend_Locale` and `Zend_Translate` do not rely on `setlocale` at all but somehow do it internally, which gives me the impression that it isn't practically feasible for enterprise level applications.

I know I could probably use `Zend_Locale` and `Zend_Translate` in my application but it also needs to support PHP4, at least for another year which is why I can't solely rely upon those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If my examination of setlocale() is correct, the answer is: No and no. The range of installed locales varies, as does their name, and the availability of a certain locale ultimately cannot be predicted with total certainty.

Answer (score 9):

You can check the return value of setlocale and at least check that it was installed. Otherwise you will have silent failures:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US') or die('Locale not installed');
```

Answer (score 0):

Feasible, yes. Wise, not at all!

Comment: What method do you use for localized dates?

Comment: intl (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) is an interface to ICU, so I trust it. Nevertheless: trust but verify, as Ronnie used to say.