# PHP setlocale has no effect

Tags: php, date, setlocale

The `setlocale()` function doesn't set the desired language (German).

---

The goal is to output month names.

This is my test code with trials so far:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8');
// Or
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro');
// Or
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');
// Or
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de');
// Or
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ge');


echo strftime('%B');
```

*Output:*

> June

*instead of*

> Juni

Any suggestions?

- I don't have ssh or other shell access.
- The script is running on a linux server.

PHP version 5.6

Comment: So you've tried other versions of the German locale, eg `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'de', 'ge');`?

Comment: You should check if the language changing succeeded by examining the return value of `setLocale`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**This solution might help if you don't have shell access to the server.**

**If you have shell access, then [Benjamin Seiller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10910009/1387233) is the best!**

As I don't have any other possibilities (shell), I've found a solution with only PHP by using the [IntlDateFormatter class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php).

```
<?php

// Example vars
$month = '6';
$year = '2014';

$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('de_DE',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'Europe/Berlin',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);

$lastMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month -1, 1, $year);

$showLastMonth =  $fmt->format($lastMonth);
echo $showLastMonth;
```

Answer (score 111):

It is quite likely that the German locale is not installed on the server you're running the script on. Do you have shell access to the server?

Then try:

```
locale -a
```

to see which locales are installed. Also have a look here [Is it feasible to rely on setlocale, and rely on locales being installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941956)

Comment: Thx for the prompt answer, unlikely i dont hav shell access. your link helped me:

Comment: Sorry and glad to hear that. Would you mind flagging my answer as "answer" then? :)

Comment: If you don’t have shell access, you can also try in PHP: `server('locale -a');` to find the names of the locales installed on your server.

Comment: The call to `system('local -a');` will have **no** effect in local Windows based development environments. So you won't be able to get it working with that solution - on Win.

Comment: Are the local names unique? Or is it 'de' on WIn7 and ' ger' on Ubuntu?

Comment: Note that the second part of the locale is mandatory — i.e. if `locale -a` returns `fr_FR.utf8`, then use `fr_FR.utf8`, not just `fr_FR`.

Answer (score 40):

For those coming here looking for `date()` doesn't localize month and weekday names:

== Pay Attention ==

date() is only able to return month/day names in English and won't be able to give you translations for other languages.

Use `strftime()` instead!

Comment: finally found what I came here to find. Thanks... tried all sugestions and no effect :( It is a bit annoying that date is this way

Comment: Use `strftime()`.

Comment: Update for 2021, `strftime()` is deprecated since PHP 8.1.

Answer (score 35):

Your code is correct. You probably just have to install the correct language package on the server you are running the script on.

In the terminal, if the language you want to use is not listed after running the command `sudo locale -a`, then you'll have to install the missing language by running the following command :

```
sudo /usr/share/locales/install-language-pack de_DE
```

(`sudo` here is optional if your user has root permissions)

Then if you double check with `sudo locale -a` you should see `de_DE.utf8`.

If you want to install french language package run

```
sudo /usr/share/locales/install-language-pack fr_FR
```

Then you'll be allowed to set your language to these in PHP by using `setlocale(...)` exactly like you did it.

**Note:** 
If you are in a non utf8 project you'll need to generate other formats from installed packages.
Here is how to proceed on ubuntu (this work on debian as well) :

edit ***/var/lib/locales/supported.d/cs*** and add the following lines

```
  fr_FR.iso88591 ISO-8859-1
  fr_CA.iso88591 ISI-8859-1
```

and run

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then by running again `sudo locale -a` you should see both **fr_FR.iso88591** and **fr_CA.iso88591** in the list and you can use it in php by calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.iso88591');`

Comment: After `install-language-pack fr_FR` I needed to use the @sephoy08 solution : `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR@euro', 'fr_FR', 'fra_fra');` and it works fine. thanks

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Installing related locale in my case giving this command "sudo /usr/share/locales/install-language-pack de_DE" was the only thing that worked for me. Pay attention to space in former command.

Answer (score 13):

Try this one:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$loc=setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
echo strftime('%B');
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot with Kirby on my local enviroment! Apparently "de_DE" doesnt work. "deu_deu" did the trick! `c::set('locale','deu_deu');`

Answer (score 7):

[PHP manual page for 'setlocale' sais](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php):

> Note: The return value of setlocale() depends on the system that PHP
>   is running. It returns exactly       what the system setlocale
>   function returns.

If you have root access (debian) here is the solution:

edit

```
/etc/locale.gen
```

You can add/remove which locales you need to use. After saving the file run:

```
locale-gen
```

and you should be fine. On my server I had to restart Apache to see changes.

Comment: The Apache restart bit is essential, I lost an hour for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In my case this does not work:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_AT'); // false
```

while this does work:

```
Locale::setDefault('de_AT'); // true
```

and this does work:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_AT.utf-8'); // true
```

Output of locale program:

```
$ locale -a
[...]
C.UTF-8
de_AT.utf-8
de_DE.utf-8
en_AG
[...]
```

Comment: hours and hours I tried many of solutions on web but.. `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_AT.utf-8');` that line saved a life. Thank you man

Answer (score 7):

This was such pain.

I wanted to translate dates to Spanish, and it was working on my localhost but not in the server (Ubuntu 18). It turned out I did not have the correct locale packages.

First I checked the installed packages to ensure they were missing

```
locale -a
```

Then I installed the Spanish UTF one using the script

```
sudo pkg-reconfigure locales
```

And then I spent hours hitting my head against the table until I realized **YOU NEED TO RESTART APACHE!**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And that's the end of my story. Hope it helps.

Comment: Or now : `sudo apt-get install language-pack-es`

Comment: Czech package: `sudo apt-get install language-pack-cs`

Comment: Also don't forget to restart php-fpm service if you use it !

Answer (score 6):

```
apt-get install -y locales locales-all
```

Comment: So true and so easy.

Comment: Made it work on my Ubuntu 20.04 server! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the underlying OS `"de_DE"` and others maybe the wrong string.

Under Windows refer this lists:

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Usually it's "DEU" or "GERMAN" under Win.

Already mentioned:

Under Linux you can see all locales with the shell command:

```
locale -a
```

Comment: Thanks for providing Windows solution! I was near to pull my hair out since all others answer I found are about linux.

Answer (score 2):

PHP have strange support for `setlocale()` on different versions.

*The tests below is on Windows (same machine), Apache 2.4 x64 (same web server), PHP x64 TS (different versions).*

[`setlocale()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) Return:

> Returns the new current locale, or `false` if the locale functionality is not implemented on your platform, the specified locale does not exist or the category name is invalid.

So, I will use the tests below on different version of PHP. Tested on PHP 7.0 - 8.1.

```
var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US'));
```

PHP 7.0, 7.1 return `'en_US'`.
PHP 7.2+ (or newer) return `false`.

```
var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en-US'));
```

PHP 7.0+ return `'en-US'`.

And for testing with multiple values to see which one will be accepted by `setlocale()` function.
I use this array.

```
$locale = ['en_US.UTF-8', 'en-US.UTF-8', 'en.UTF-8', 'en-US', 'en_US', 'en'];
var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale));
```

PHP 7.0, 7.1 return `'en_US.UTF-8'`.
PHP 7.2+ return `'en-US.UTF-8'`.

As you can see that if PHP did supported `'en_US'` for old version it doesn't mean will be supported on newer version.

For OP's case, maybe try with this array to see which locale will be accepted.

```
$locale = ['de_DE.UTF-8', 'de-DE.UTF-8', 'de.UTF-8', 'de_DE', 'de-DE', 'de', 'ge'];
var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale));
```

The result maybe different on Linux or other OS.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Rico Neitzel for the hint.
Instead of trying to format php date, use strftime.
To see the first 3 letters of month name in your language (Ex. Dez instead of Dec from Dezembro and not December), follow the locale instalation instructions above, and then:

<s>date command: date('d M Y')</s>  // impossible to change from English

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, "pt_BR"); // Portuguese, replace with your locale
echo strftime('%e %b %G');
result: "4 Dez 2016"

/**
 * datelo funcion (date with locale)
 * Credits: Sergio Abreu 
 * http://sites.sitesbr.net
 * NOTE: Depend on availability of the locale in server.
 *
 */

function datelo( $str, $locale='en_US', $time=null){

  if( $time === null){  $time = time(); }

  if ( preg_match("/[DlFM]/", $str)){

     setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

     $dict = array( 'd'=>'%d', 'D'=>'%a', 'j'=>'%e', 'l'=>'%A', 'N'=>'%u', 'w'=>'%w', 'F'=>'%B', 
      'm'=>'%m', 'M'=>'%b', 'Y'=>'%G', 'g'=>'%l', 'G'=>'%k', 'h'=>'%I', 'H'=>'%H', 'i'=>'%M', 
      's'=>'%S', 'S'=>'', 'z'=>'%j', 'n'=>'%m', ' '=>' ', '-'=>'-', '/'=>'/', ':'=>':', ','=>',');

     $chars = preg_split("//", $str);
     $nstr = '';

     foreach ($chars as $c){
        if ($c){ //skip empties
          $nc = $dict[$c];
          if( $c === 'n'){ // Fixes the extra zero
            $nc = preg_replace("/^0+/", '', strftime( $nc));   
          }
          elseif( $c === 'z'){ // Fixes the extra zero and decrease 1
            $nc = preg_replace("/^0+/", '',  strftime( $nc)); // 023 turns 23
            $nc = intval($nc) - 1;
          }          
          $nstr .= $nc;
        }
   }
   return strftime( $nstr);     

  }else{ // not localized
    return date( $str, $time);
 } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your are on a **Red Hat machine** you can run :

```
localedef -v -c -i de_DE -f UTF-8 de_DE.UTF-8
```

Then restart your Apache server

Answer (score -1):

I hope this help por php 7.4

When I tried to print a date in spanish, it give me the english version.

So I print in terminal all my lang packages:

```
# locale -a
```

it gives me no one for spanish, so a run:

```
# sudo /usr/share/locales/install-language-pack es_ES
```

and change te setlocale in code to:

```
<?php 
setlocale (LC_TIME, "es_ES", "es_ES.iso88591", "spanish");
?>
```

after that, restart the php service with:

```
/etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm restart
```

and that's it

Comment: Read the question. There is no command line possibility on that server.