# PHP date - get name of the months in local language

Tags: php, date, localization

I have this part of the function, which gives me name of the months in English. How can I translate them to my local language (Serbian)?

```
$month_name = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i));
```

Where `$i` is the number of the month (values 1 - 12). See also [PHP:mktime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).

Comment: `strftime`, and install the proper locale, & set your current locale to serbian.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/setlocale):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');
$month_name = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i));
```

In this case it would set it to French. For your case it should be one of the following:

1. `sr_BA` - Serbian (Montenegro)
2. `sr_CS` - Serbian (Serbia)
3. `sr_ME` - Serbian (Serbia and Montenegro)

Comment: My `date` is locale unaware, my `strftime` is not. If yours is locale aware... what's your PHP version?

Comment: But notice that [`setlocale` sets the locale process wide](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-notes) (causing unexpected behavior with multiple threads when using multi-threading). Thread safe alternative: [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php)

Comment: This solution is incorrect. Let's say it's 2019-01-30, the function mktime() without the fifth and sixth parameter will use the current day and year, so if it's 2019-01-30 and you want to know $i = 2 (February), the result will be March, because 2019-02-30 doesn't exist and it will be interpreted as a date in March. To avoid this problem, use for example: mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2019). Anyway, don't use this solution, because it will give the wrong result on certain specific dates. So many incorrect answers on Stackoverflow ...

Answer (score 23):

You should use [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/setlocale) and [`strftime()`](http://php.net/strftime):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'sr_CS');
$month_name = strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i));
```

Comment: it has issues with time zone on datetime object if you use setTimezone() and use getTimestamp()

Comment: this work for me, sadly on my machine `setLocale()` not affect `date()`

Comment: `strftime()` deprecated in PHP 8.l

Answer (score 18):

Here is an example with [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php)

```
$format = new IntlDateFormatter('sr_CS', IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 
              IntlDateFormatter::NONE, NULL, NULL, "MMM");
$monthName = datefmt_format($format, mktime(0, 0, 0, $i));
```

Comment: Hello, here please change locale to "en" and month number to 11. Then it shows me dec and not Nov. Can you please guide?

Answer (score 12):

For all who struggle with German (and `de_DE`), make sure you are using the right language code. Login to your server and run [`locale -a`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10909911/1066234) to see a list of all available ones. For me it shows:

> C
> C.UTF-8
> de_AT.utf8
> de_BE.utf8
> de_CH.utf8
> de_DE.utf8
> de_LI.utf8
> de_LU.utf8
> ...

You need to use one of those codes.

Then you can use:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8');
$date_now = date('Y-m-d');
$month_available = strftime('%B %Y', strtotime($date_now));
$month_next = strftime('%B %Y', strtotime($date_now.' +1 month'));
```

and "März 2020" etc. get displayed correctly.

Answer (score 6):

This question asks how to get a list of months, I only see hints, not a complete code answer so:

If you have `IntlDateFormatter` available - which is available in most of the cases, you can create a formatter in a given locale and repeatedly push a date to it created just based on month number

```
// or any other locales like pl_PL, cs_CZ, fr_FR, zh, zh_Hans, ...
$locale = 'en_GB';
$dateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    $locale,
    IntlDateFormatter::LONG, // date type
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE  // time type
);
$dateFormatter->setPattern('LLLL'); // full month name with NO DECLENSION ;-)
$months_locale = [];
for ($month_number = 1; $month_number <= 12; ++$month_number) {
    $months_locale[] = $dateFormatter->format(
        // 'n' => month number with no leading zeros
        DateTime::createFromFormat('n', (string)$month_number)
    );
}
// test output
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($months_locale);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Note:** `LLLL` takes care of not-declining, but it does **not take care of the lowercase/uppercase of the first letter** if the languages has such things.
Good example is that you can get `January` for `en_GB` but `leden` for `cs_CZ`

 If you want all letters lowercase => use [`mb_strtolower($month_name);` - docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)

 If you want just the FIRST letter to be upper case =>

 => use [`mb_convert_case($month_name, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');` - docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php)

**Always use `mb_*` functions or their variations for locale-originating strings !**

So no, don't use <del>`ucfirst`</del> !

Answer (score 1):

It is good idea to pass the encoding when setting the locale:

```
 <?php    
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Belgrade');
 setlocale(LC_TIME, array('sr_CS.UTF-8', 'sr.UTF-8'));
```