# Does PHP's DateTime support other formats/locales?

Tags: php, date

Well, the question is pretty obvious I guess.

If I have:

```
$now = new DateTime();
print $now->format('l, M d');
```

Can I output that date in a different language?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845554/php-date-get-name-of-the-months-in-local-language

Comment: It is not a `language` but a date time format. Change that and the question becomes much clearer

Comment: @SalmanA That involves the date function. I would like to use DateTime

Comment: you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744952/php-how-to-format-a-given-datetime-object-considering-localegetdefault

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP's intl extension has the [`IntlDateFormatter`](http://php.net/IntlDateFormatter) for this purpose.

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'de-DE',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'America/Los_Angeles',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN
);

$date = new DateTime;
echo $fmt->format($date);
```

Comment: Also note that you're able to set a custom pattern via `$fmt->setPattern($thePattern)`. The patterns are described here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime