# Months name is not showing in German in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to display months name in PHP but it is not showing in German language
in MYSQL, my date is showing as `2021-01-23` which I converted into months by using PHP function Month(), `MONTH(beginn)`

PHP Code -

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8');
echo  (date("F",strtotime($month)));
```

Comment: try the second and third answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845554/php-date-get-name-of-the-months-in-local-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$loc=setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
echo utf8_encode(strftime("%B",strtotime("2021-06-23")));
```

> Convert June to Juni

Edit: some characters in German are utf8 enncoded utf8_encode function solve it. Like `März`