# Get Locale Date in PHP - 2022

Tags: php, date, locale

How should I get the Day and Month (i.e. `Friday`, `August`) with the corresponding locale (i.e. `de_DE`) in PHP?

Most examples use `setlocale()` and `strftime()`, the last one being deprecated as of PHP 8.1.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP date - get name of the months in local language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845554/php-date-get-name-of-the-months-in-local-language)

Comment: @kmoser Most of the answers in there are using `strftime`...

Comment: [This answer uses `IntlDateFormatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66378193/378779), not `strftime()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct about `strftime()` being deprecated, and `date()` (being a part of `DateTimeInterface`) will not work with `setlocale()`. One thing that will work with it is [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php):

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('de_DE',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL
);

echo $fmt->format(time());
```

Will output:

> Samstag, 27. August 2022 00:58:15 GMT

You can play around with the Predefined Constants to specify different formats for the DateType and TimeType. I used FULL for my example. Read more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php#intl.intldateformatter-constants).

You can also change the [Pattern](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.getpattern.php)

```
$fmt->setPattern('yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss z');
echo $fmt->format(time());
```

To output (for example):

> 20220427 01:04:51 GMT

Comment: I realize the `IntlDateFormatter::FULL` can be replaced by `null`

Comment: I've updated my answer, correcting the link to the Predefined Constants. Correct, passing in null will cause it to get your default locale defined in your php.ini file. See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.configuration.php#ini.intl.default-locale).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the DateTime class with a local, e.g

```
$copenhagen_timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Copenhagen');
$today = new DateTime('now', $copenhagen_timezone);
```

So easy to calculate the time difference afterwards