# How to extract month from "created_at" column and display in "Brazilian Portuguese"?

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, laravel-blade, strtotime

In my table, in "created_at" column:

```
2023-01-03 08:43:40
```

In my view I am using this code to extract the date:

```
<span>
   {{ date("F", strtotime($item->created_at)) }} de 
   {{ date("Y", strtotime($item->created_at)) }}
</span>
```

The result shows:

```
JANUARY de 2023
```

Is there a way to extract this month in Brazilian Portuguese?

To show like this:

```
JANEIRO de 2023
```

Comment: Eloquent timestamps are by default [cast to Carbon objects](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), so you don't need to use strtotime. You can use the carbon methods, which includes [localization](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)

Comment: also don't forget to define your locale and timezone in `config/app.php`

Comment: The duplicate has a very good answer using INTL here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66378193/2310830