# PHP setlocale doesn't work

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, locale, php

I try to set the locale from fr_FR to us_US in PHP (php-fpm) with nginX on my raspberry-pi.
Here is my code:

```
<?php

system('locale -a');
/*
C POSIX en_US.utf8 fr_FR fr_FR.iso88591 fr_FR.iso885915@euro fr_FR.utf8
So the en_US locale is well installed
*/

echo locale_get_default();
/* fr_FR */
echo setlocale(LC_ALL, '0');
/*
LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;
LC_MESSAGES=C;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;
LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
*/

var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8', 'en_US.UTF8'));
/* bool(false) */

var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF8'));
/* string(10) "fr_FR.UTF8"
useless, but it shows that setlocale works with the already set locale */
?>
```

I don't understand why `setlocale` returns `false`.
It seems something doesn't work but I don't manage to find what.

Comment: So what _does_ the final setlocale call return?
Try using var_dump() instead of echo, as "echo false" might not display anything.

Comment: A great step forward: with `var_dump` instead of `echo`, `setlocale` returns `bool(false)`. The question now is why `setlocale` returns `false`?

Comment: Another possibility could be this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10910211/1387233

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem after installing additional locales on debian machine running nginx with php5-fpm

To fix the problem I had to restart php5-fpm.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me after I have ran:

```
sudo apt-get -y install language-pack-pt

service php7.1-fpm restart

<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso88591', 'pt_BR.utf8');
echo \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMonth()->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (note **On Windows**):

> **On Windows**, setlocale(LC_ALL, '') sets the locale names from the
>   system's regional/language settings (accessible via Control Panel).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php