# PHP money_format not displaying currency symbol

Tags: php, currency, money-format

I'm trying to use [money_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) to obviously add separators and a currency symbol to a number I have. I've seen plenty of examples where they work, but for some reason the currency symbol does not display.

```
$_price = '10995';    
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
echo money_format('%n', $_price);
```

results in:

```
10995.00
```

I can do this and it nearly works, however as I understand, that's not the point?:

```
echo money_format('&pound;%n', $_price);
```

results in:

```
£10995.00
```

I can see that this also formats the number close to how I want, without the .00:

```
echo '&pound;'.number_format( $_price );
```

results in:

```
£10,995
```

Comment: have you verified that you have locale files loaded/available - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10910009/689579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Sean's link in the above comment, I can see that the locale for en_GB was not created.

once created with `sudo locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8` I had the currency symbol