# De_de locale not working

Tags: php, locale

Website with several languages(lv,ru,en,pl,de). When i'm setting de_DE, setlocale(LC_ALL, 0) returning "C", on other languages everything OK.

my code of setting locale:

```
// Set locale
if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale . '.utf8', $locale . '.utf-8', $locale . '.UTF8', $locale . '.UTF-8', $locale . "@euro")) {
    // Set current locale
    setlocale(LC_ALL, '');
}
```

i also checked debian for locales they are also there:

```
...
de_CH.utf8
de_DE
de_DE@euro
de_DE.iso88591
de_DE.iso885915@euro
de_DE.utf8
de_LI.utf8
...
```

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909911/php-setlocale-has-no-effect

Comment: i don't need to output date, i'm using gettext functionality. 'de', 'ge' haven't helped me

Answer (score 0):

Was wrong value in variable de-De not de_DE