# Spanish date showing day of week and month in Enlgish

Tags: php

I am setting a local:

```
            setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
```

Then I am generating a date:

```
echo strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y", strtotime($screening->timestamp));
```

But the day of the week, and the month show up in English. Output:

```
Wednesday, 27 de April del 2016
```

How can I get the date in Spanish?

Comment: Are you sure es_ES locale is installed on the server? Run `locale -a` and see if it's there

Comment: That seems be the problem. Spanish isn't on the list. How do I install new locales on my machine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909911/php-setlocale-has-no-effect

Comment: What type of machine do you have ? OS and Flavor.

Comment: Just use: `setlocale(LC_ALL,"spanish"); ` so `echo strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y");` will return `jueves 21 de abril del 2016`