# Date language problem when deploying to Netlify

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, netlify, static-site

This is my first time deploying a site in Netlify. I'm using [Jigsaw](https://github.com/tightenco/jigsaw) in order to achieve this.

Everything is ok, besides the date language that is exported in production.

When I generate my production site locally it works fine displaying the date in Spanish:

[image: Kenny Horna's blog: Date displaying in Spanish]

I'm not uploading the same exact files to netlify but using the netlify.toml to run the same command in order to generate the *same* files:

```
# netlify.toml

[build]

command = "npm run production"
publish = "build_production"
environment = { PHP_VERSION = "7.2" }
```

But in production, the site is displaying the month in English:

[image: Kenny Horna's blog: Date displaying in English]

You can check it live [here](https://kennyhorna.com/blog/desplegando-aplicaciones-laravel-6-en-lemp-stack-ubuntu-18-y-nginx-git-hooks-certificado-ssl-parte-ii/).

#### Note

To display the date I'm doing this:

```
@php(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES'))

<p class="text-gray-700 text-md md:mt-0">
{{ $page->author }}  • {{ strftime("%d de %B, %Y", $page->getDate()->getTimestamp()) }}
</p>
```

Have you ever experienced something like this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

---

#### Update

Modified the `netlify.toml` to this but still without any luck:

```
[build]

command = "npm run production"
publish = "build_production"

[context.production.environment]
PHP_VERSION = "7.2"
LC_ALL = "es_ES"
```

Comment: try pass locale to ```[context.production]
  environment = {  }
```

Comment: and check phpinfo, maybe locale not changed

Comment: @Dry7 could you give me more details please?

Comment: my hunch is that the @php command (setlocale (LC_ALL, 'es_ES')) is ignored. So you need to try other ways to setting the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that worked (thanks to the link provided by *Kalimah Apps*) was to change this:

```
@php(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES'))
```

To this:

```
@php(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES.UTF-8'))
```

Now is working as it should.

Answer (score 4):

Probably setlocale is not working. Since the same code works on your machine it is possible that Spanish locale is not installed on hosting machine. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10910009/529024.

Also, setlocale returns **the new current locale, or FALSE if the locale functionality is not implemented on your platform, the specified locale does not exist or the category name is invalid.** [setlocale](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

So in this case you could check the return value and see if the local has changed.

Comment: Thanks, I followed one of the advices of your provided link and it worked.