# Convert date got from API to German format

Tags: php

I want convert this date and time to german.

```
2019-12-22 19:45
```

to

```
Dienstag, 22. Dezember 2019 - 19:45

                $start = strtotime('2019-12-22 19:45');
                setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE', 'de_DE.UTF-8');
                // create format

                // output (using current time)
                echo strftime(" %d. %B %Y",$start);
```

got this result which not in german :(

```
22. December 2019
```

I am using wordpress and making shortcode, getting data from api just for informations

UPDATE

I am using this code now but still not got result like i want.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE', 'de_DE.UTF-8');
$dt = new DateTime($event->start , new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));    
echo $dt->format('d. F Y, H:i'); exit;
```

got this result

```
22. December 2019, 19:45
```

I tried this code but its not working.

Comment: What does `setlocale` return? Do other PHP scripts run on the same server that might call `setlocale` as well? The locale is per-process, not per-thread, so it's possible that another script changes the locale between your call to `setlocale` and `strftime`.

Comment: You might also run on a server that doesn't have the German locale, or the user your script runs under doesn't have permission to change the locale. You should investigate these things and then update your question with more info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP setlocale has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909911/php-setlocale-has-no-effect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a PHP extension for DateTime API called `dt`. You can find it [here](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt)

Using it is very easy:

```
echo dt::create("2019-12-22 19:45","Europe/Berlin")->formatL('d. F Y, H:i','de');
//22. Dezember 2019, 19:45
```

Comment: It would be preferable to vote to close this question as duplicate of [PHP setlocale has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909911/php-setlocale-has-no-effect), and add your answer to the other question.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend reading more about DateTime Formats https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php
Your solution:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE', 'de_DE.UTF-8');
$time = date_create_from_format('U'; , '2019-12-22 19:45', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin')); 

echo strftime(' %d. %B %Y', $time->getTimestamp());
```

Comment: can you help specifically what should i do to get above results ?

Comment: Updated with Berlin TimeZone