# Laravel carbon date trasnlation

Tags: laravel

Hey everyone, i need some help on translation carbon values date, time etc....,

for example using `{{ date('M d, Y',strtotime($something->created at)) }}`
then it will be displayed as —> `Apr 03, 2021`

my question how can we translate "Apr" to other languages, i have spent more than 3 days on this case searching for a possible way in the last 3 days, but there was no luck :(, if you could help me and the other who need this solution

also i have tried more than one way for this such as writing this on providers.php

```
$app = $this->app && method_exists($this->app, 'getLocale') ? $this->app : app('translator');
        $locale = $app->getLocale();
        Carbon::setLocale($locale);
        CarbonImmutable::setLocale($locale);
        CarbonPeriod::setLocale($locale);
        CarbonInterval::setLocale($locale);
```

Comment: you can't use date() to translate, you should format it with Carbon object e.g. $something->created_at->locale('ab_cd')->format('dddd MMMM YYYY')

Comment: try something like `now()->locale($locale)->translatedFormat('M d, Y');`. https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using formatLocalized method? Google it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `setlocale` function before setting the localized format in Carbon. The problem in your code is that, the way you are setting the locale, it is stateless. It is not being saved.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');                     
echo $date->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20058254/8607640

Another solution for you could be saving the locale in session and thus making it saved for the session.