# gettext only translate to English in PHP

Tags: php, gettext

I'm spanish, and making tests internacionalizing a text width PHP, i only get it translated to english.
I got this structure of files:

```
locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/con los ficheros messages.mo y messages.po
locale/es_ES/LC_MESSAGES/con los ficheros messages.mo y messages.po
locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/con los ficheros messages.mo y messages.po
```

Every files have the key word "Servicios" translated to each languaje.

And in PHP i have this code:

```
<?php
putenv("LANG=en_US");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");
bindtextdomain("messages", "locale");
textdomain("messages");
?>
```

When i put the code 'en_US' show the good translation, but when i change it to 'es_ES' or 'fr_FR' that way:

```
<?php
putenv("LANG=es_ES");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
?>
```

or

```
<?php
putenv("LANG=fr_FR");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR");
?>
```

still showing the translation to English

I am working on Widnows 7 and the function

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] ;
```

returns to
"es-ES,es;q=0.8" 
always,

Which problem could it be?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that the languages are not installed on the server your running the script on - do you have shell access to the server? Then try

```
locale -a
```

to see which locales are installed. Also have a look here [Is it feasible to rely on setlocale, and rely on locales being installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941956/is-it-feasible-to-rely-on-setlocale-and-rely-on-locales-being-installed)

**NOTE:**

be careful with the `LC_ALL` setting, as it may introduce some unwanted conversions. For example, I used

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "Dutch");
```

to get my weekdays in dutch on the page. From that moment on (as I found out many hours later) my floating point values from MYSQL where interpreted as integers because the Dutch locale wants a comma (,) instead of a point (.) before the decimals. I tried `printf`, `number_format`, `floatval`.... all to no avail. `1.50` was always printed as `1.00` :(

When I set my locale to :

```
setlocale (LC_TIME, "Dutch");
```

my weekdays are good now and my floating point values too.

Comment: Hi, sorry, i don't understand the answer, how can i execute 'locale -a'?. I have a local server apache \r\n Apache Version :
2.4.9   - Documentation
PHP Version :
5.5.12   - Documentation
Server Software:
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Thanks!